# Kafka Stateless KStream : How to commit until failure point upon exception?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say the Kafka stream emit Events 1,2,3,4,5 in a sequence. When Event 5 errored out, the kafka stream processor quits as expected. However it fails to commit until Event 4. When I restart the Spring boot stream application, the stream once again start from Event 1,2,3,4 and then fails at 5.

Just for more clarity, I am reading "latest" messages from the stream. The topic has 10s of messages, so it is not streaming from the beginning.

What is the appropriate way to commit until Event 4, when the 5th event fails before my stream processor thread quits ?

My Kafka Streams Configuration:

```
 @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
  KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "ms-orders-app");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 3000);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class.getName());
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
```

My Topology code:

```
@Autowired
  public Topology buildTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {

    Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
        schemaRegistryUrl);

    Serde valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

    var crmOrderStream = streamsBuilder.stream(S_ORDERS,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

    crmOrderStream
        .mapValues(orderValueMapper())
        .filter(orderCompletePredicate())
        .mapValues(enrichedOrderValueMapper());
    return streamsBuilder.build();
  }
```